# How to apply a function in an iterable list

Tags: list, function, loops, functional-programming, ocaml

so I am new to OCaml and im having some trouble with lists.
What I have is a List  of chars as follows:

`let letters = [a;b;c;d]`

I would like to know how can I iterate the list and apply a fuction that takes as arguments every possible combination of two chars on the list (do_someting char1 char2), for example: a and b (do_something a b), a and c .... d and b, d and c; never repeating the same element (a and a or c and c should not happen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OCaml is a functional language, so we want to try to break down the procedure into as many functional pieces as we can.

Step 1 is "take a list of things and produce all combinations". We don't care what happens afterward; we just want to know all such combinations. If you want each combination to appear only once (i.e. `(a, b)` will appear but `(b, a)` will not, in your example), then a simple recursive definition will suffice.

```
let rec ordered_pairs xs =
  match xs with
  | [] -> []
  | (x :: xs) -> List.append (List.map (fun y -> (x, y)) xs) (ordered_pairs xs)
```

If you want the reversed duplicates (`(a, b)` *and* `(b, a)`), then we can add them in at the end.

```
let swap (x, y) = (y, x)

let all_ordered_pairs xs =
  let p = ordered_pairs xs in
  List.append p (List.map swap p)
```

Now we have a list of all of the tuples. What happens next depends on what kind of result you want. In all likelihood, you're looking at something from the built-in [`List` module](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html). If you want to apply the function to each pair for the side effects, `List.iter` does the trick. If you want to accumulate the results into a new list, `List.map` will do it. If you want to apply some operation to combine the results (say, each function returns a number and you want the sum of the numbers), then `List.map` followed by `List.fold_left` (or the composite `List.fold_left_map`) will do.

Of course, if you're just starting out, it can be instructive to write these `List` functions yourself. Every one of them is a simple one- or two- line recursive definition and is very instructive to write on your own.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to Silvio's answer, for large lists, we don't need to actually generate the entire list in memory and then iterate over it. Instead we can create a [sequence](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html) of ordered pairs.

In order to do this, we need to keep track of three things:

- The current prefix.
- The rest of the list after that prefix.
- The rest of the list after the prefix *again* so that we can update the first argument and still have it when we iterate to the end of that list.

```
let rec ordered_pairs_seq lst () =
  let rec aux pre cur_lst lst () =
    match cur_lst, lst with
    | [], _ -> ordered_pairs_seq lst ()
    | x::xs, _ -> Seq.Cons ((pre, x), aux pre xs lst)
  in
  match lst with
  | [] -> Seq.Nil
  | x::xs -> aux x xs xs ()
```

Then using this:

```
# let print_tuple (a, b) =
    Printf.printf "(%d, %d)\n" a b
  in
  pairs_seq [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
  |> Seq.iter print_tuple;;
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
(3, 4)
(3, 5)
(4, 5)
- : unit = ()
```

Of course, if you need the whole list:

```
# pairs_seq [1; 2; 3; 4; 5] 
  |> List.of_seq;;
- : (int * int) list =
[(1, 2); (1, 3); (1, 4); (1, 5); (2, 3); (2, 4); (2, 5); 
 (3, 4); (3, 5); (4, 5)]
```